# QML does not play well with system theme

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyqt5

I have a very basic QML file:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 100
    height: 100
    title: 'Hello World'

    Column {
        TextField {
            id: text
            width: parent.width
            text: 'Text Field'
        }
        Button {
            text: 'Button'
        }
        Label {
            text: 'Label'
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get different results when running it with PyQt5 vs qmlscene:
I have set a dark theme for my desktop, and qmlscene works just as expected. But with PyQt5 is seems to inconsistently pick up the dark theme: the text color changes, but the background not always. Thus I get some unreadable colors in the `TextField` and `Button` (show white text on a white background). The `Label` however has no issues.

PyQt5 [image: PyQt5]
qmlscene [image: qmlscene]

For the Python part I have:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

# Create the application instance and a QML Engine
app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

engine.load(QUrl('test.qml'))
engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What is happening here? How do I fix this?

---

### Update

As suggested I took a look at the code of [qmlscene](https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/5.12/tools/qmlscene/main.cpp) and stumbled on two differences: First, it uses `QQuickView` instead of `QQmlApplicationEngine`, but that does not seem to play any role here. The other one is using `QApplication` instead of `QGuiApplication`. With that change, I get the correct behavior.

So the issue seems solved, but I don't really understand why. I only found that `QApplication` is a subclass of `QGuiApplication`. Could someone explain why only one of them seems to work properly?

Also, I don't know yet whether this is a general Qt issue or somehow related to Python. Although PyQt5 and PySide2 show the same behavior, so maybe a general thing?

Comment: The best way is to compare your code with [qmlscene](https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/5.12/tools/qmlscene/main.cpp) one.